# how can we add videos on scrollbar?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

I am developing a videos managing Apps. I add videos on Scroll view.

There is nothing visible except black screen. This code is working properly,only adding black views on scroll,content is display.

If any one have any idea please provide me.

```
(void)LoadVideosToScrollView
{    
    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *videoDirectory=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/videos"];
    NSFileManager *fileManger=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *docEnum=[fileManger enumeratorAtPath:videoDirectory];
    MPMoviePlayerController *localMoviePlayer;
    CGFloat xAxis=10;
    NSInteger n=0;
    NSString *fileName;

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(560, 200)];
    while ((fileName=[docEnum nextObject]))
    {
        NSString *filePath=[videoDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",fileName]];
        //if file exist then file will be added on ScrollView
        if ([fileManger fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
        {
            NSURL *urlForFile=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
            NSLog(@"%@",[urlForFile description]);
            localMoviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:urlForFile];
            localMoviePlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
            localMoviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=NO;
            localMoviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone;
            [localMoviePlayer prepareToPlay];
            tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
            [localMoviePlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
            [localMoviePlayer.view setTag:n];
            [localMoviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(xAxis,5,150,120)];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:localMoviePlayer.view];
            [moviePlayerContainer addObject:urlForFile];
            xAxis+=155;
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

i have developed this code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to Use `AVPlayer` instead to `MPMoviePlayerController` as with `AVPlayer` you can render the video to specific source view - in your case the scrollview.

best of luck

Answer (score 0):

You didn't called play method

```
// Plays items from the current queue, resuming paused playback if possible.
- (void)play;
```

---

Try the next code

```
 _moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];

[[_moviePlayer view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[[self view] addSubview: [_moviePlayer view]];

_moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

[_moviePlayer play];
```

---

And if you have many videos on one scrollview you will have problems with memmory managment, for optimizing process of showing list of videos, you can use UITableView and put videos on each cell, becouse UITableView already has own memory manager for it's cells.